# java bouncy castle RSA 4096 decryption padding error

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, rsa, padding

I have been trying for two days to decrypt a file whith the private key containing 'lolilol' after having encrypted it with the public key rsa 4096. I then get padding errors, I tried everything to do, I get the error `Javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error`.

Even after reading the doc on the padding I did not succeed: encryption works fine, but decryption contains an error.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class GenerateRSAKeys{


    private Key pubKey;
    private Key privKey;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Desktop\\nomFichier_entrant.ext";
        String output = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Desktop\\nomFichier_entrant.ext.enc";
        String dec = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Desktop\\nomFichier_entrant.ext.dec";
        String publicKeyFilename = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Desktop\\HR_pubkey_prd.pem";
        String privateKeyFilename = "C:\\Users\\toto\\Desktop\\PE_privkey_prd.pem";

        GenerateRSAKeys generateRSAKeys = new GenerateRSAKeys();

        /*         if (args.length < 2)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: java "+ generateRSAKeys.getClass().getName()+
            " Public_Key_Filename Private_Key_Filename");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        publicKeyFilename = args[0].trim();
        privateKeyFilename = args[1].trim(); */
        generateRSAKeys.generate(publicKeyFilename, privateKeyFilename);

        //generateRSAKeys.encrypt(input, output);
        generateRSAKeys.encrypt(input, output);
        generateRSAKeys.decrypt(output, dec);

    }

    private void generate (String publicKeyFilename, String privateFilename){

        try {

            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            // Create the public and private keys
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            BASE64Encoder b64 = new BASE64Encoder();

            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            /* SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

            keyGen.initialize(4096, random);

            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            pubKey = pair.getPublic();
            privKey = pair.getPrivate(); */

            SecureRandom random = createFixedRandom();
            generator.initialize(4096, random);

            KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            pubKey = pair.getPublic();
            privKey = pair.getPrivate();

            System.out.println("publicKey : " + b64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()));
            System.out.println("privateKey : " + b64.encode(privKey.getEncoded()));

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(publicKeyFilename));
            out.write(b64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()));
            out.close();

            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(privateFilename));
            out.write(b64.encode(privKey.getEncoded()));
            out.close();


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static SecureRandom createFixedRandom()
    {
        return new FixedRand();
    }

    private static class FixedRand extends SecureRandom {

        MessageDigest sha;
        byte[] state;

        FixedRand() {
            try
            {
                this.sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                this.state = sha.digest();
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find SHA-1!");
            }
        }

        public void nextBytes(byte[] bytes){

            int    off = 0;

            sha.update(state);

            while (off < bytes.length)
            {                
                state = sha.digest();

                if (bytes.length - off > state.length)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, bytes, off, state.length);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, bytes, off, bytes.length - off);
                }

                off += state.length;

                sha.update(state);
            }
        }
    }

    public void encrypt(String input, String output) {
        File outputFile;
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] inputBytes;
        byte[] outputBytes;

        try {
            outputFile = new File(output);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            inputBytes = new byte[(int) input.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);
            outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            // System.out.println(new String(inputBytes, "UTF-8"));

            System.out.println("encrypt");
            System.out.println(new String(outputBytes, "UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("fin encrypt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(String input, String output) {
        File outputFile;
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] inputBytes;
        byte[] outputBytes;

        try {
            outputFile = new File(output);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
            inputBytes = new byte[(int) input.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);
            outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            // System.out.println(new String(inputBytes, "UTF-8"));

            System.out.println("decrypt");
            System.out.println(new String(outputBytes, "UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("fin decrypt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know the encryption works fine? Maybe it is corrupted?

Comment: It's true. Just a new file created with the code below : èBÓ| ¦Î´G¹DÅÄ¢LÅ¬ÐßqÍ
nüÈú¹;Ú‹nšÇfó§½Bö‡Û6XRw}¿¹:Q‚èÂ¼Q-!ÜóŠÇöïv ¨ò'øa}ŽÁãúcÝøcF^dÆé}ÚÛÝö‘×>ËÍqz«V®¥Öôt÷ã¥WŒpƒ…9O,nZeBÔ Þ*ðü4i3úm÷Îu)Æ1¨‰±±{&!qÁ<Ýú)ºÑ"¤Q˜*t~ÑÙ#²$Ÿ<@µ‚È²õ0jkq Y—ý´ëœ_#¶48€lž¦8ªA©Ük.œµçRèëêµ]‡Tÿ¢h‘ÿP˜ÂLç´ÿny
Þ_9ìÁ·9Q=$çã_]¿Jm¥ÐÕ«U…a¨nð÷òÞ]gøH(ÏTOxDtëÊ€æžU·¿ŽþYºÔ³Š3‡>ëT~¼â5$Ñ¼øòÛ¡¯ xìç|t¾„¥
Çb¼(ãæ"á/~á2gVâUkŠXaóXôÄáúÇ,™$p
ZÚªí;8›ô>çp•œQHCˆ”‡ÊRû©ošC‰TÄ¼²ÑÔvˆ«A"õ"íwÏs‘~(ã{§îÛ R
‹ÿj:óŒKÌ w®?V¹Ô
Q°Œ¯éÆÎ¦ÔéÚ¥{óË>¬÷z‹dÈtýÍ6w¾åýA–

Comment: but how do you know this is what it SHOULD be maybe this is wrong

Comment: It still doesn't work on java and I have tested it on linux and it works on linux with the command: openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privkey.pem -in $file.key.enc -out $file.ext.key.dec. I use after the decrypt file $file.ext.key.dec to decrypt the file encrypt : file.ext.enc with the command : openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -kfile $file.ext.key.dec -in $file.ext.enc -out $file.ext

Comment: Maybe there is a problem for loading the private key. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: It finally works, the problem comes from loading private key, solution ; https://www.txedo.com/blog/java-read-rsa-keys-pem-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your code:

- You're never closing the file streams. If you don't do that, it might happen that no data is actually written. If the ciphertext is not (fully) written then the decryption will obviously fail.
- A `FileInputStream` doesn't give an accurate measure of how much data the underlying file contains. You have to use the `File` class for that:

  ```
  File inputFile = new File(input);
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
  byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
  ```
- When you're reading file contents, you must always check how much you read and use exactly that amount:

  ```
  int readBytes = inputStream.read(inputBytes);
  byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, readBytes);
  ```
- Always use a fully qualified Cipher string. `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. In OpenJDK it defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");`. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`.

Here is the full code of those two methods:

```
public void encrypt(String input, String output) {
    File inputFile;
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] inputBytes;
    byte[] outputBytes;

    try {
        System.out.println("encrypt");

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        inputFile = new File(input);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        inputBytes = new byte[(int) input.length()];
        int readBytes = inputStream.read(inputBytes);
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, readBytes);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        System.out.println("fin encrypt");

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void decrypt(String input, String output) {
    File inputFile;
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] inputBytes;
    byte[] outputBytes;

    try {
        System.out.println("decrypt");

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);

        inputFile = new File(input);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        int readBytes = inputStream.read(inputBytes);
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, readBytes);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        System.out.println("Decryption result: " + new String(outputBytes, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("fin decrypt");

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: B : Thanks a lot. It works with my file test. I'm going to check with the oters.

Comment: It seems you're still having problems. I've run it and it works as expected. See [the full class](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/6ad21d2f012ecee8ec33d04d8cbd8653). I've commented some unnecessary lines and removed the "BC" flag.

Comment: Hi Artjom B, In fact I have a client that encrypts a file with the public key. In my application, I have to decipher only, not encrypt. I decrypt with private key and that's when I get the padding error. Maybe the problem comes from the random.

Comment: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:365)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2189)
 at deciphertodeploy.Test24RsaFileIO.decrypt(Test24RsaFileIO.java:168)
 at deciphertodeploy.Test24RsaFileIO.main(Test24RsaFileIO.java:39)

Comment: I see. So, then you have to decode the corresponding private key. That's not part of your current question and it would make a mess if you edit your question to include that. Please ask a new question about that issue. I've answered your current question with working code.

Comment: If the client uses the same code, then it should work. I've also tried to encrypt with one instance and decrypt with another. It works for me. So, there must be something else going on here (which you can describe in your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)). You would need to describe how you're transmitting the file (perhaps it's corrupted).

Comment: It still doesn't work on java and I have tested it on linux and it works on linux with the command: openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privkey.pem -in $file.key.enc -out $file.ext.key.dec.   I use after the decrypt file $file.ext.key.dec to decrypt the file encrypt : file.ext.enc with the command : openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -kfile $file.ext.key.dec -in $file.ext.enc -out $file.ext

Comment: It works the problem comes from the private key. The way it was loading was not good.

Comment: @Khaled The openssl issue was revealed after I've given my answer. It would change *this* question completely. I understand that you've asked *this* question without fully explaining your actual issue, but you did still ask it and I *answered* it. Since then you've asked another question with the openssl issue which I don't *want* to answer, because that is not my expertise. If this question is not what you're looking for and my answer didn't answer *this* question, then just delete this question. I've lost all interest by now.

Comment: Thanks for all you have done Artjom B., I'm just not used to using forums.

Comment: The code was good for encrypt and decrypt. We have just to use a pemparser class to load the private key.